# Selecting a Point datatype from MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Good Day,

I am trying to get a point from an SQL column. CUrrently it is encoded as a string of characters: Gþ`C@Ëóàî¬Ë]À

So is there any way to actually decode it to get the actual value?

Answer (score 1):

Use MySQL's [`AsText()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/functions-to-convert-geometries-between-formats.html#function_astext) function:

```
SELECT AsText(myPoint) FROM myTable
```